# Evolutionary algorithm: executing dna (list of commands) without compiling beforehand

Tags: performance, parsing, compilation, artificial-intelligence

I have begun writing an evolutionary algorithm. It consists of a two dimensional world (like a large chess board) of cells that can contain at most one agent and a certain amount of food. The agents can walk around in this world, attack each other, request information about their own cell or their neighbouring cells and create offspring etc.

The agents themselves consist of a program that is executed each turn, and DNA. This program consists of a combination of about 30 different commands (MoveTo, SaveDate, GetData, Atack, etc). A very simple example could be this:

```
MoveTo(RandomByte());
```

Or a little more complicated:

```
SaveDate(Number(50),Number(2));
MoveTo(GetData(Number(2)));
```

The program is built by reading the DNA when the agent is created, a DNA element could look like this:

```
DNAElement(8, Instructions.SaveData, new List<int> { 9, 13 }));
```

The 8 is the unique id of this element/instruction, then SaveData is the instruction type, 9 and 13 are the parameters (it are the unique ids of instructions) so basically these are a type of reference.
Special cases are the start element, which defines where to start reading the dna, and the Number element, whose parameter is not an unique id but an actual number. The dna elements are stored in a list, so if I would want to say this in DNA:

```
MoveTo(RandomByte());
```

It would could look like:

```
dna.Add(new DNAElement(5, Instructions.MoveTo, new List<int> { 2 }));
dna.Add(new DNAElement(0, Instructions.Start, new List<int> { 5 }));
dna.Add(new DNAElement(2, Instructions.RandomByte, new List<int> { }));
```

This dna is then read (using a resursive method) and the string: “MoveTo(RandomByte());” is build, then this string is added in a large string that describes a whole class, this large string is then compiled at runtime, casted to an interface, and the resulting objects seem like regular agent objects.

The problem however is that compiling the string at runtime takes a lot of time and children are often created, so I somehow need another way to be able to “execute” the DNA. I was reading about delegates, but can’t figure out if I can use these (don’t fully understand them yet). Do you guys know a way that is both efficient at reading the dna (possibly only at birth like is done now), and which produces a type of program that  can be efficiently executed each turn?

EDIT: Any suggestions on for example a different "DNA structure" that might be work better are ofcourse more then welcome

Comment: Not sure this encoding is optimal. As for the execution, if each "DNA" simulation is short, you'd better be interpreting it instead of compiling (it's probably one of the very few cases where interpretation should be used). In similar scenarios I translated ASTs into flat stack VM bytecode (ideally, a direct threaded code) and executed it straight away.

Comment: What would you suggest as a more optimal encoding? And when would you say that a program is to long to interpret and instead should be parsed?

Comment: If a combined time of compiling and running is higher than the time needed to directly interpret the code, you have to use interpretation. With the one-off code which is not running for a while in a tight loop it is often the case. As for encoding - tree representations are not very suitable for genetic algorithms, at least not directly. I found it useful in many cases to have a two-stage generation: a chromosome is encoded in a concatenative language (i.e., flat, easy to slice at any point, etc.), and it is evaluated into a tree (like, a genotype vs. phenotype), which is then executed.